# Unmarshalling in Jaxb with different tag with same name

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I need to unmarshall a xml file which can return tag in following two ways.

```
  <return_msg>Invalid Bank Code.</return_msg>
```

Second one

```
 <return_msg>
  <status_desc>Ok</status_desc>
  <status_code>0</status_code>
 </return_msg>
```

How can I create JAXB model class for this tag

Comment: i dont think its possible.May be you can give a try by using  two different namespace for the tag return_msg

Comment: But I am getting this xml as a response. Can you explain it a bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tried, but you should be able to use this :

```
@XmlRootElement(name="return_msg")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ReturnMsg{

    @XmlElement
    private String status_desc;

    @XmlElement
    private String status_code;

    @XmlMixed
    private List<String> mixedContent;

    //Getters and Setters

}
```

The mixed content should contains your "Invalid Bank Code." message if it's there.

Comment: no it is not working. In case of using only first 2 tags in XML document. JAXB content corresponding to first two tag are getting set with correct value and mixedContent is getting null value as required but in case for " <return_msg>Invalid Bank Code.</return_msg>" every jaxb model contents are getting a null value. I need to have mixed content set to "Invalid bank code",

Comment: Thanks it worked. I was actually taken the wrong tags.